# Getting Error "could not install windows 10 sdk" while installing the visual studio 2015 enterprise edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am trying to install the visual studio 2015 in Windows 10 pc. But It is showing the error that "all features are not correctly installed" and hash code is incorrect. here I am posting the shot of dat. [image]

can any one help me.

Comment: Did internet is enabled ? or Install SDK separately

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise but not choose Windows 10 SDK and Emulator (Install VS2015 and choose custom installation, uncheck Windows 10 SDK and Emulator options).
   [image: pic]
2. Download and install the standalone [Windows 10 SDK and Emulator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)  .
3. Modify Visual Studio 2015 and in this time check all options under "Universal Windows App Development Tools".

Comment: did not get with this.. Can u suggest me that from where I can download the visual studio 2015 setup file.

Comment: @Archana I have update my answer, You can try download Windows 10 SDK

Comment: Actually that was the firewall issue. Sorry and Thanks for ur response